# Is it possible to display 2 months in antdesign datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, antd

I am not sure if this is a feature that ant design provides and I couldnt find anything like that in their library.
so, let me know if it's possible. and if possible, then how?
Here's what I want it to display like
[image]

If anyone has done that already , then please let me know

Comment: not possible without forking the antd's datepicker. However you can raise a enhancement to antd.